# CSS positioning - mobilemenubar

Tags: javascript, html, css, element, positioning

I came across a problem I do not understand and don't know how to solve on a project.
I am designing the mobilemenu of a website.
The problem is only occurring in the mobilemenu so to reproduce the issue a max window width of <1023 is needed.

The menu can be expanded with the burger icons on the top right corner as intended. The menu works fine but when the menu is not expanded, on the menubar on some random places, (they can be easily found by just hovering over the green area) the cursor becomes a pointer and clicking launches a menu item (that was not visible and i do not know why it can be clicked there)

To make it easier to localize the problem I extracted the important lines of the code to this codepen: https://codepen.io/bvonr/pen/rNMEpqZ

```js
(function(){
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger-container'),
        header = document.querySelector('.header');
    
    burger.onclick = function() {
        header.classList.toggle('menu-opened');
        menu-item.classList.toggle('activemenu');
    }
}());
```

```css
/*Header generell */

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #24603c;
  z-index: 2;
}

/* Mobiles Menü */
@media (max-width: 1023px) {

.header {
         background: #24603c;
     height: 50px;
     width: 100%;
     overflow: hidden;
     transition: all 0.5s ease-out, background 1s ease-out;
     transition-delay: 2.2s;
     z-index: 1;
}
.header > a {
  height: 50px;
}
.header > a > img {
  height: 50px;
}

.header .burger-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.header .burger-container #burger {
  width: 18px;
  height: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: -4px auto 0;
  top: 50%;
}
.header .burger-container #burger .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.header .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.header .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(0deg);
}

.header {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: auto;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.65s;
}
.header ul.menu {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 48px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.burger-container {
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99), opacity 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
}

.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.49s;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.42s;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.28s;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.21s;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.14s;
}
.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 0.07s;
}

.header ul.menu li.menu-item a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 2.35;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 100%;
}
.header.menu-opened {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #24603c;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in, background 0.5s ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.header.menu-opened .burger-container {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar {
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.01, 0.165, 0.99);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.topBar {
  transform: translateY(4px) rotate(45deg);
}
.header.menu-opened .burger-container #burger .bar.btmBar {
  transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item {
  transform: scale(1) translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.27s;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 0.34s;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 0.41s;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 0.48s;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 0.55s;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(6) {
  transition-delay: 0.62s;
}
.header.menu-opened ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(7) {
  transition-delay: 0.69s;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="?module=start"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/Logo%21_Logo.svg/1920px-Logo%21_Logo.svg.png"></a>
    <div class="burger-container">
      <div id="burger">
        <div class="bar topBar"></div>
        <div class="bar btmBar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>


<ul class="menu">

  <li class="menu-item">
    <a href="?module=start">CLUB</a>


    <ul class="menulist">
       <li class="menulevel1">
        <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
       </li>
    </ul>


  </li>

  <li class="menu-item">
     <a href="Hockey">HOCKEY</a>


     <ul class="menulist">
         <li class="menulevel1">
           <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
         </li>
      </ul>


</li>

<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="Tennis">TENNIS</a>


  <ul class="menulist">
      <li class="menulevel1">
         <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
      </li>
  </ul>


</li>

<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCDujF-QJ9YYeBxCHsFtz9Cg" target="_new">UHLEN.TV</a>


  <ul class="menulist">
     <li class="menulevel1">
        <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
     </li>
  </ul>


</li>

<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="?module=profile">MY.HTCU</a>


  <ul class="menulist">
       <li class="menulevel1">
          <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
       </li>
  </ul>


</li>

<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="?module=admin">ADMIN</a>


  <ul class="menulist">
      <li class="menulevel1">
          <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
      </li>
  </ul>


</li>

<li class="menu-item">
  <a href="tests">TESTSEITE</a>


  <ul class="menulist">
     <li class="menulevel1">
         <a class=" " href="Ueber-Uns">ÜBER UNS</a>
     </li>
  </ul>


</li>

 </ul>
</div>
```

If someone knows why the menuitems appear there and how i can fix this, I would highly appreciate your help.

I am coding the website unsalaried so i am far from an expert and would appreciate any help.

Comment: _“(they can be easily found by just hovering over the green area)”_ - and you can also easily right click there then, and via “inspect element” find out, what exactly gets displayed in those positions … and you will find out, that it is your `ul.menu` element. You have made the `li` and `a` display as block, so that they go over the whole width - but the menu is still _there_ …

Comment: Just add `display: none` to your `menu` class when the burger menu is not visible and that should be it

Comment: menu {display:none} solves the issue but i am not able to set it back to display block when i open the menu. I dont get the correct javascript together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this line...:

```
transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px)
```

...in the CSS rule for `.header ul.menu li.menu-item:nth-child(1)`

Or more precisely the `translateY(-30px)` in there, which moves all menu links up by 30px.

Since you are hiding your `li` elements with `opacity: 0`, the top `li` is still there partly; not visible, but clickable (i.e. the part of it that isn't hidden by `overflow: hidden` on the header).

So you should either use `display: none` instead of `opacity: 0` on the list items (or better on the whole `ul`), or avoid using that `transform: translateY(-30px)` setting

Comment: Removing: transform: scale(1.15) translateY(-30px) worked. 
As I would have to change the display: none back to display block when clicking the menu, I will just remove the line of code. Thanks